# link_to confirm, no matter the answer will always execute the action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, link-to, confirm

When I press the link, the confirmation pops up, but no matter if I answer Yes or No, it will always execute the action and delete the record.

### View:

```
link_to "Remove", gamep, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Remove "+@player.name+" from "+gamep.game.title+"?"
```

### Action:

```
def destroy
  @gameplayer = GamePlayer.find(params[:id])
  @gameplayer.destroy
  respond_to do   |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @gameplayer.player }
  end
end
```

Yes I have

```
javascript_include_tag :defaults
```

Edit:
I had to fix this originaly using a jquery.rails.js because the :delete method wasn't working. Without this, there is no confirmation, and the link_to just acts like a normal link.

For some reason, when I installed the 'jquery-rails' gem, it didnt put a 'jquery-ujs.js' in my 'public/javascripts' folder.

> C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.16
>
> C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.1.1

application.js

> // Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
>
> // This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults
>
> //= require jquery
>
> //= require jquery_ujs
>
> //= require_tree .

Comment: I think you've missed a bit of important info. Rails has upgraded to 3.1 and it's no longer necessary to keep your javascript in public folder. From now on the default is to keep all your assets in app/assets. The best advice I could give you is to generate a brand new rails 3.1 app and slowly move your code over to it. It seems to me as though you are trying to manually upgrade an old app.

Comment: I have made a new app, installed every required gem, placed all the files in the correct folders, and am no longer using any custom js besides the default rails3.
I still have the same problem, the confirmation appears, yes or no, still executes the action.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3.1, you should be using "application", not "defaults", otherwise none of your javascript will get loaded properly:

```
javascript_include_tag "application"
```

Also, you don't need to manually include any additional javascript files, as the application manifest (`app/assets/javascripts/application.js`) will already pull them all in. Just make sur e**all** of your JS files are sitting in `app/assets/javascripts`, not 'public/javascripts`.

And make sure you are **not** using the `rails.js` file from previous versions of Rails. This has been replaced by the `jquery-rails` gem in Rails 3.1.

Comment: The version I'm using is 3.1.1.
I updated the rails.js like you asked, and the problem remains.

Comment: Ahh.. that's the problem, you're on 3.1.1. See my updated answer.

Comment: And if you just downloaded the `rails.js` file and added it, get rid of it now.

Comment: I forgot to mention something very important. I'm editing the question.

Comment: I will probablyneed to get all these js re-organized to get this working.

Comment: If I use "application" instead of :defaults, none of my js are being loaded.

Comment: can you also post your application.js file too

Comment: you need to add `//= require_tree .` on a new line after jquery_ujs - note the fullstop at the end of the statement, it's necessary, don't leave it out

Comment: I've added it. But unfortunately I don't see any difference.
If I use `javascript_include_tag "application"` it still doesn't call the other js files.

Comment: I've just realised you have your javascript in the public folder, which is no longer the best place to keep them. Rails has had a bit of a rewrite and stuff like javascripts, images and stylesheets all live under `app/assets` now

Comment: Yes, these are on the public folder because the app was originally from a previous version of Rails. 
But its wierd, because I actually made a new app on Rails 3.1.1, and refactored the code to fit. Thinking of it now, I don't understand why it's using the public folder. Every other app I've generated has all these files on the 'assets' folder.

Comment: I updated my answer to specify that you need to put all your JS files under app/assets/javascripts.

Comment: I have done that, but the js files still aren't loading.
`$(document).ready(function() { alert("test!"); });` will only work with `:defaults`

Comment: Do you know why would jquery-rails gem not generate the jquery-ujs.js file?

Comment: It doesn't need to generate it, it's already included in the gem. You just need to make sure your `app/assets/application.js` file has `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` in it.